# python tarfile.py "file could not be opened successfully"

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a tarball that I can't open using python:

```
>>> import tarfile
>>> tarfile.open('/tmp/bad.tar.gz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tarfile.py", line 1672, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

but I'm able to extract the file with no problem on the command line.

```
$ tar -xzvf /tmp/bad.tar.gz
```

I've traced the python `tarfile` code, and there's a function "`nti`" where they're converting bytes. It gets to this line:

```
obj.uid = nti(buf[108:116])
```

and blows up. These bits (for the UID) coming through as eight spaces. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue8978
maybe compiled error on zlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly it looks like the bug is in `tarfile.py`'s `nti` function:

```
n = int(nts(s) or "0", 8)
```

The fall-through logic (`or "0"`) is not working because `s` is spaces, not `None`, so `int()` blows up.

I copied `tarfile.py` from `/var/lib/python2.7/` and wrapped that particular line with a try/catch, which fixed me up:

```
    try:
        obj.uid = nti(buf[108:116])
    except InvalidHeaderError:
        obj.uid = 0
```

It's a hack solution, though. Really I'd prefer that the python folk took a look at it and fixed the "`or "0"` logic.

**Update**

Turns out the tarball was created by the `maven-assembly-plugin` in a Java 6 project that had just been upgraded to Java 7. The issue was resolved by upgrading the `maven-assembly-plugin` to `2.5.3`.

Comment: So the tar file was corrupt? Having non-numbers in offsets 108 to 116 disqualifies it from being a tar file.

Comment: @EugeneK *shrug* If we change the definition of "corrupt" to "does `tar` open the file?" then no, it was not corrupt. :-)

Comment: @EugeneK I'm totally with you though, from the perspective that python is likely following the spec, and this file was not behaving correctly. On the other hand... if you don't have the UID and GID bits set? should that mean python should *fatally* freak out? Seems like an overrreaction.

Comment: I'm not sure what the alternative is other than throwing an exception. You can only guess so much. GNU Tar Util does work differently and is much more fail safe. For example, Tar spec says it has to be 512 aligned (I think, or was it that it has to end in 512 0's), many things will fail if that's not true, but GNU Tar Util still works.

Comment: @inanhutshellus I think if you don't have UID and GID bits set, then it has to put arbitrary 8 bits for each of those, else the header is misaligned and the dearchiver has to guess where the data starts, i.e. still 512 in or sooner?

Comment: @EugeneK If you're saying "There are two bugs: One, `maven-assembly-plugin:2.3` put spaces where it should've put zeroes, and they fixed it. Two, the `tar` command on command-line is more failsafe than python cares to be." then that's good enough for me. :-)

Comment: I believe that's what I'm saying. Good job the on the debugging. Curious what UID and GID `gnu tar` uses when it's not correct. It might be more safe to put something that isn't 0. :)